# Precise tracing of IIS and/or SQL 

Tags: sql-server, iis, asp-classic

I am experiencing a performance bottle-neck in this website: http://oceanosdecolor.es/ and I'm not able to find it. If you try, you'll see any page (for example, homepage) takes a long time to load.

The first time you execute a page, the site reloads to detect client device, but that's only the first time and then it keeps client device so it doesn't reload again.

I log traces of the execution to database but I don't get useful information as, according to the log, the execution of the whole homepage happens in the same 1 second, but I can see that the homepage takes more time to load.

The IIS log (when trying locally) doesn't help as this also gives information in seconds, not miliseconds, and again, it says everything happens in the same second, and anyway running locally is much faster than on the server.

So, I ask for help in any tool to monitor performance with more accuracy or any technique I could use.

Thank you

Comment: Well, I marked as answered the questions that where answered correctly, not the ones that wheren't a solution. I tryed to vote for peopled who answered, even if the answer didn't solve the problem, but it says I need some reputation or so to vote, so I'm sorry about that but there's nothing I can do about it...

Comment: please provide more information... what do you mean by "locally versus" ? Is the server on a shared host ? Is there some proxy involved ? Is the DB on the same server as the ASP.NET app ?

Comment: thank you. it's a shared host, DB is in a different server (don't really know if "physically different"), I trace the actions from ASP to DB and I see everything happens in 1 second, so the bottle-neck might be in the rendering itself, which sounds quite strange! I have other sites in the same hosting companies and same CMS platform (http://proyecto9.es/ http://nozines.com/) and never so this, at least I didn0t appreciate it...

Comment: Front-end is classic asp

Comment: @user761076 since I don't know ASP classic I can't really help except for the "standard advice" - check for memory leaks, network problems/performance, proxy problems, system load etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your answer might not lie with IIS or SQL Server. According to the Developer Tools in Chrome, your actual page execution and sending out the HTML takes 400ms on first load from my location. The problem is you have a tangle of CSS files (many of which are not being found and causing extremely long delays). Also you have a lot of requests.

I would install Yahoo's [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) for your favourite browser. This will give you a whole bunch of recommendations for what is running slow on your site from an end-user perspective.

To use the Developer Tools on Chrome: right click on your page, hit "Inspect Element" and then go to the "Network" tab and then hard-refresh your browser (shift-F5).

A few of the problems I see are: commun.css (2.5 seconds and failed), layout.css (400ms and failed), jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.min.js (800ms and failed).

Find the reason for these failing and fix it and I'm sure your site will load faster. Also try use [CSS image sprites](http://css-tricks.com/158-css-sprites/) wherever possible to cut down on the number of requests.

Comment: Thanks man! I'm sure you're right. About image sprites I knew about them but always thought the effort in _image editing_ and _css adjusting_ did not equilibrate in requests reduction, do you think is a really big reduction in time and band width? Anyway, I'll try the tools you tell me

Comment: I definitely think so. Requests are what delays your page loads more than anything (assuming reasonably quick scripts). Think about it, for each request the server has to send the request, wait for the response, and then transfer the data. By combining your images into sprites whenever possible you decrease the send/wait times and possibly the amount of data being transfered. Look at the link I sent, it has a sprite generator reference inside it. Saves time.